# MySQL selecting tables where user exists

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have a mySQL table called "user" that contains a userid and a password or something. Then I have other tables for different purposes, such as a table for their favorite food, which would contain their userid and favorite food.

Is there a way to query for tables that contains a specified userid and checks whether they have an entry in that table?

So if I have three tables called favorite_food, favorite_drink, and favorite_candy, but userid only had values in favorite_food and favorite_drink, I want the query to return favorite_food and favorite_drink.

I'm a beginner and I couldn't quite grasp the concept of linking. Userid is the primary key of user and the other tables reference it?

Answer (score 0):

Read more about UNION. I think that this is what you need.

```
SELECT * from favorite_food where `userid` = 50
UNION
SELECT * from favorite_drink where `userid` = 50
UNION
SELECT * from favorite_candy where `userid` = 50
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL "linking" is represented by `JOIN`s. Since (as you indicated) some users will not have 1 or 2 favorite objects we will need to use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s. Then we will have `NULL`s in the output in place of missing favorites.

```
In your case:

SELECT u.userid, f.food_name, d.drink_name, c.candy_name
FROM user u 
   LEFT JOIN favorite_food  f ON u.userid=f.userid
   LEFT JOIN favorite_drink d ON u.userid=d.userid
   LEFT JOIN favorite_candy c ON u.userid=c.userid
ORDER BY u.user.id
```

This will give you favorites for **all users** in your `user` table.